Inputs from console do not become String in program through nextLine
I am making a program that first asks the user to input a number from the console to choose which umber type they'd like to convert to the other two, after which the user enters a number in the form of a string which is converted to the other two systems also as a string. I've ran into a problem where the program just stops, not letting me input the string bin from the console.
package testing;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestingClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int num=0;
        for (;num!=4;) {
            System.out.println("1. Binary to hexadecimal and decimal");
            System.out.println("2. Hexidecimal to binary and decimal");
            System.out.println("3. Decimal to binary and hexadecimal");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");
            num = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            switch (num) {
                case 1: System.out.println("Enter a binary number");
                String bin = sc.nextLine();
                if (isBinary(bin)) {
                    String bin2 = binToHexAndDec(bin, true);
                    System.out.println(bin2);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The number entered is not a binary number, please try again");
                }
                break;
                case 2: System.out.println("Enter a hexadecimal number");
                break;
                case 4:
                break;
                default:
                break;
        }
        }
    
    }
    public static String binToHexAndDec(String bin, boolean isHex) {
        String toHexAndDec = "";
        int decimal = 0;
        for (int i = bin.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
            decimal += ((int)(bin.charAt(i)-'0'))*(Math.pow(10, i));
        }
        if (isHex) {
            for (;decimal!=0;); {
                if (decimal%16>9) {
                    char ch = (char)(decimal%16-9+'a');
                }
                else {
                    char ch = (char)(decimal%16+'0');
                }
                toHexAndDec += (char)(decimal%16+'0');
                decimal/=16;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (;decimal!=0;); {
                toHexAndDec += (char)(decimal%10+'0');
                decimal/=10;
            }
        }
        return toHexAndDec;
    }
    public static boolean isBinary(String bin) {
        boolean isBinary = true;
        for (int i =0;i<bin.length()||isBinary==false;i++) {
            char ch = bin.charAt(i);
            if (ch>'1'||ch<'0') {
                System.out.println("The number you entered is not a binary number, please try again");
                isBinary=false;
            }
        }
        return isBinary;
    }
}


I originally found a solution online using the implementation of sc.nextLine(); in between the num = sc.nextInt; for the switch and the String bin = sc.nextLine();. Before implementing sc.nextline; the program would entire skip over String bin = sc.nextLine(); but now the whole program comes to a halt. I rebuilt the whole program afterwards and learned that without calling the method isBinary() the String bin inputs successfully. I'm not sure why this is and I need to be able to call the method to convert the string to the other two number systems.

Step through your program with the debugger and see exactly what it's doing.

The problem is your for loops: for (;decimal!=0;); { ... } is effectively an empty for loop (for (;decimal!=0;);) followed by a block ({ ... }) and since the empty for loop (for (;decimal!=0;);) never changes the value of number it is an endless loop. Remove that extra ; directly after the for statement: for (;decimal!=0;) { ... }

I'd also suggest that while (decimal != 0) is a more readable way of writing such a loop.
